# Best javascript library for HTML/DOM to Canvas conversion

Tags: html, dom, canvas, converters

I need a good js library which able to concatenate 2 canvas, some text strings and some images in one solid image (canvas). There is outbound divs out of each element which can be rotated and zoomed also.

Actually it is t-shirt design constructor, I need to have complete image after user pressed "Save" button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [libcanvas](https://github.com/theshock/libcanvas) for easy drawing and object manipulating. It's a fast opensource library. And get image from canvas like this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var resultImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: just learn something and write my own utility to merge my specific DOM structure. Works well.

Still waiting for answers, just curious.